# Raspberry PI - I2C not writing data

Tags: c#, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian, i2c

I'm trying the new `System.Device.Gpio` library in .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/iot) with my Raspberry PI 3B+, but the I2C communication is giving me some trouble.

I want to reproduce the behavior of some python code that is already working, starting with some simple data writing and reading:

```
I2cConnectionSettings settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(1, 0x18); // I2C BUS is 1, ADDRESS is 0x18
I2cDevice device = I2cDevice.Create(settings);
device.WriteByte(8);
Console.WriteLine("Byte written: " + device.ReadByte().ToString());
```

The result is giving me is always `0`, without any error, while the expected result should be `8`.

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

1. On the raspberry make sure you enabled I2C in raspi-config
   (sudo raspi-config, Interface Options, Enable/Disable autom... I2C kernel module)
2. using System.Device.I2c; // Manage Nuget Packages..
3. The "DeviceAddress" of the I2cConnectionSettings is the address of the "Slave" you are writing a single byte to with I2cDevice.**WriteByte**. The **Slave** device e.g. an Arduino receives this byte in it's **receive** data event. This can be used for sending commands to the device.
4. When you call device.**ReadByte** you actually send a request to the device to answer with data. An Arduino **Slave** for example would get this request in it's **request** data event and could send back something (int the case above one byte). This should be something different than 0 since 0 is also returned by the function if no data was read.